# mergesort in python gives error message "list indices must be integers, not tuple"

Tags: python, list, tuples, mergesort

I can't understand the error I get from this.
Where have I defined a tuple?
How can I solve it?

Lista should be a list with values and keys `[(key1,value1),(key2,value2),...)`.

`sx` and `dx` are the integers that define the begginin and the ending of the sublist.

This is the program

```
def merge(lista,sx,dx):
    cx = (sx + dx)/2
    i = sx
    j = cx + 1
    app = []
    while (i<=cx and j<=dx):
        if lista[i][1]<=lista[j][1]:
            app.append(lista[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            app.append(lista[j])
            j += 1
    while(i<=cx):
        app.append(lista[i])
        i += 1
    while(j<=dx):
        app.append(lista[j])
        j += 1
    for z,k in app,range(sx,dx+1):    
        lista[k][0] = z[0] #ERROR
        lista[k][1] = z[1]


def mergesort(lista, sx = 0, dx = -1):
    if dx == -1:
        dx = len(lista)
    cx = (sx + dx)/2
    if(sx<dx):
        mergesort(lista,sx,cx)
        mergesort(lista,cx+1,dx)
        merge(lista,sx,dx)
```

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "occorrenze.py", line 78, in <module>
    mergesort(lista)
  File "occorrenze.py", line 55, in mergesort
    mergesort(lista,sx,cx)
  File "occorrenze.py", line 55, in mergesort
    mergesort(lista,sx,cx)
  File "occorrenze.py", line 55, in mergesort
    mergesort(lista,sx,cx)
  File "occorrenze.py", line 55, in mergesort
    mergesort(lista,sx,cx)
  File "occorrenze.py", line 55, in mergesort
    mergesort(lista,sx,cx)
  File "occorrenze.py", line 55, in mergesort
    mergesort(lista,sx,cx)
  File "occorrenze.py", line 57, in mergesort
    merge(lista,sx,dx)
  File "occorrenze.py", line 46, in merge
    lista[k][0] = z[0]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

EDITED:

> I think what you want would be -
>
> ```
> for z in range(sx,dx+1):
>     lista[z] = app[z-sx]
> ```

Thank you Anand, you 've solved my first error, now I have an other error...

```
    if lista[i][0]<=lista[j][0]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `for z,k in app,range(sx,dx+1)`: here,  `k` is the return value from `range`, it does not iterate over the elements in `range`.

Comment: @dhke could you explain the behaviour of k exactly?
Thanks

Comment: Scratch my comment, I just re-checked syntax and this should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want would be -

```
for z in range(sx,dx+1):
    lista[z] = app[z-sx]
```

you may also consider changing the following line -

```
dx = len(lista)
```

to

```
dx = len(lista) - 1
```

Comment: I have no error, but it doesn't sort seems :(

PS: I solved it, thank you! :D